# Redirect the website URL Form to a particular Page

Tags: javascript, forms, url, redirect

My Form Works Successfully But in website URL it only Shows the address to a Form.I have multiple Pages in which the Form button shown.All I want when a user  click on The Form for Page A for that Particular page it should shown as

> "www.form.com?test=page A" - this should displayed on website URL

or when the Form is submitted the receiver should view that this form coming from Page A..In the Form field I hidden this fields name 'Test' so the user cannot see it but only the receiver can view it that its coming from Page A

On my Html code I have redirected to the Build in Form.
Here is my java script code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/form/y.php/test2"></script><no1script><a href="https://test.com/forms/discount" title="Online Form">Online Form - </a></no1script>
```

How  to  show it to my Website URL

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as "How can I redirect with a specific GET parameter?", correct me if I'm wrong.

The solution for that would be quite simple: Append the GET parameter to the forms action:

`<form action="target.php">`

gets

`<form action="target.php?test=page_a">`

so that on target.php if you evaluate the GET values, *test* has the value *page_a*.

Comment: you right..There is nothing wrong  with my  Java script code here?..My Form build on a Software then where i can put the form Action?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to hide the post data, you can try something like:

```html
<form action="https://test.com/forms/discount" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" name="couponCode" value="secret">
  <input id="myform" type="submit">
</form>
<script>
document.querySelector("#myform").click();
</script>
```

Note: This won't stop any web ninjas, so you should think of something else, like web tokens that function sortta like private public keys.